# Android json viewpager action bar fragmentpageadapter

Tags: android, json, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I have created `action bar` and `viewpager`, I have three `fragment`. Each of the `fragment` I `parsed json` and can show each `listview` . My problem is : If I `click` second `fragment` and then I go back(`click` firs `fragmet`) when I go to the next `fragment` and then if I go to a front `fragment` at this situation  Loading information from the `server` occurs twice, I use `AsyncTask` class to load info from `server`.

**Below is a my code :**

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:

        return new SendItemsFragment();
    case 1:

        return new RecivedItemsFragment();
    case 2:

        return new FavoriteItemsFragment();

    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return 3;
}

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
private String[] tabs = { "test1", "test2", "test3" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.color.white);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.acttitle);
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(d);

    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
            | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp_main);
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.menu_example);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
            | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });

    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
    // R.drawable.background)); background viewpager

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
  }
```

This is - one of the fragment's code. Similar to all three of them. The only difference is that the load of data from the server, And also use the AsyncTask class, each of which had a different.

```
public class SendItemsFragment extends Fragment {
private String URL = "*******************************************";

public static String KEY_title = "title";
public static String KEY_description = "description";
public static String KEY_image = "image";
public static String KEY_journal = "journal";
public static String KEY_JournalID = "JournalID";
public static String KEY_pubDate = "pubDate";
public static String KEY_statID = "statID";
public JSONArray jsonarray;
public ListView list;
public TransparentProgressDialog pd;
public JSONParser jsonparser;
static DealBoxAdapter adapter;
ProgressDialog pDialog, pDialog1;
static String fontPath2 = "font.ttf";
public static Typeface tf2;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
public ImageLoader imageLoader;
static final int DIALOG_ERROR_CONNECTION = 1;
private int screenSize;
private LoadDataAllChanelsToServer loader;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.send_items, container, false);
    list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    pd = new TransparentProgressDialog(getActivity(), R.drawable.loader);
    screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;
    loader=new LoadDataAllChanelsToServer();

    loader.execute();
    return rootView;
}

private class LoadDataAllChanelsToServer extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        jsonparser = new JSONParser();

        JSONObject jsonobject = jsonparser.getJSONfromURL(URL);
        try {

            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put("journal", jsonobject.getString(KEY_journal));
                map.put("image", jsonobject.getString(KEY_image));
                map.put("title", jsonobject.getString(KEY_title));
                map.put("description",
                        jsonobject.getString(KEY_description));
                map.put("JournalID", jsonobject.getString(KEY_JournalID));
                map.put("pubDate", jsonobject.getString(KEY_pubDate));
                map.put("statID", jsonobject.getString(KEY_statID));

                itemList.add(map);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return itemList.toString();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            if (pd != null) {
                pd.dismiss();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        try {
            adapter = new DealBoxAdapter(getActivity(), itemList,
                    screenSize);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
  }
```

that's all :)
if anyone knows solution please help me 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should cancel async task when your `Fragment` is destroyed.

```
private LoadDataAllChanelsToServer mLoader;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mLoader = new LoadDataAllChanelsToServer();
    mLoader.execute();
    ...
}

@Overide
public onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if(mLoader != null) {
        mLoader.cancel(true);
        mLoader = null;
}
```

this way when fragment is destroyed `AsyncTask` will be canceled.

You can also set `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)`. This way, since you have only 3 `Fragments`, no `Fragments` will be destroy and therefore your `onViewCreated` will only be called once.

Comment: i added this onDestroy method ,but i have problem again in only first fragment

Comment: My bad. First part of my answer should resolve unnecessary `try cache` block in `postExecute` thou. Have you tried `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)`. This should be solution if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: i did not understand you i added onDestroy method only with try catch and i did not understand what means  ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2).what this means where i can to add this  ?

Comment: in your `MainActivity.onCreate()` call `viewPager. setOffscreenPageLimit(2)`. This will preserve 2 fragment to the left and 2 to the right before destroying them when you swipe left and right.